# rails how to show a search result based on current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, locale

Rails app is detecting the different locale from pages and displaying correctly except in the results  from a search form in index page.

my routes:

```
 get 'search' => 'mymodel#show'
```

my controller:

```
def search
 if @mymodel = mymodel.find(params[:id])
 else 
  redirect_to mymodel_path
 end
end
```

my search partial (one for each locale and detecting correctly):

```
<div class="actions"><br>
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:id) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Search shows correct results but always in default locale "english". 
It does not detect the current locale being used.

I have different show pages based on locales. They work correctly throughout the application except in displaying results from the search form.

How to display the results in the correct locale? 
Thanks for any help, i can't figure out how to do this....

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb` file change the **search** methods route like the following:

```
scope "(:locale)" do
  get 'search' => 'mymodel#show'
end
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work for me. It keeps rendering the show action in the default locale english. I had a similar problem with the main logo link at the top left and i fixed it with class="navbar-brand" href="/mymodel?locale=es" from the different locales layouts. Could i do something like this maybe ? how?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it creating a new view, a new action and a new route for each locale. 
So I now have a different partial, view, route and action for each locale.

Definitely not the dry way but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Emu's solution works if you change

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag("/"+I18n.locale.to_s+"/search", method: "get") do %>
```